# wget isn't converting some links properly

Tags: wget

I'm trying to get a "working copy" of `google.com` using `wget`.
The command I use is:

```
wget --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --no-host-directories -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36" -e robots=off https://www.google.com
```

In the resulting page(in google chrome) the google logo is missing with their corresponding errors in the console.

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND   /C:/images/nav_logo242.png:1

`nav_logo242.png` can be found in `root/images/nav_logo242.png` where root is the folder where wget outputted the files.
Also there is a `root/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png` which also doesn't appear.

I'm using ubuntu on windows 10.

Is such behavior expected? If not how can I fix it.

Comment: Are you accessing the website via the Ubuntu WSL or from Windows itself?

Comment: @kemotep I did try for both Ubuntu WSL and Windows.

Comment: You need to fix the path in the index.html or whatever is rendering the webpage. So the file cannot be found because /C:/images/nav_logo doesn't exist or at least exist in a context that the webpage can read from. With this being an instance of WSL it gets pretty confusing. Is it only an issue with the path being wrong? Or is there permission issues such that the webpage cannot read from certain directories? What browsers are you using in both WSL and Windows? Check the console in those browsers to see more information about the error.

Comment: @kemotep for both `WSL wget`  and `Windows wget` the same issue persists, 
I don't think there are permission issues, 
yes the main issue is the path, if I edit the paths manually(add a dot in front) the logo is rendered.